# implementing hot deck imputation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data-set that contain both numeric and categorical data like this

```
subject_id   hour_measure   heart rate      blood_pressure       urine color
3               4                60              
4               2                70          60                   red 
6               1                            30                  yellow
```

I tried various methods to handle missing data such as the following code

```
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else next(iter(x.mode()), None)
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[cols].transform(f))
df= df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

but these techniques didn't give me the result I want. I tried to use hot deck imputation I already understand the concept of the hot deck imputation technique, as it is a suitable way to handle both numeric and categorical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your data as input for machine learning, you can convert the columns containing text to numbers (e.g. a LUT, or convert the colors to corresponding RGB values.

Regarding the second part of your question : could you be more specific about what results you are expecting and what your current code produces?

Comment: in the above code the feature filling if it  registered at least one for patient. but if the feature didn't fill for patient at all, in this case it still missing. my question is how to use hot deck imputation to fill this missing values according to weights or matching between rows

Comment: i didn't prefer to convert categorical to numbers , therefore i asked about this technique

Comment: I am assuming that hour_measure indicates the hour at which the readings are recorded in sequence and subject_id corresponds to an individual. How about, for heart_rate and blood_pressure, imputing them with weighted average of the latest 5/4 hours(configurable depending on the requirement) for each subject_id separately, and for urine_color imputing it with the latest hour's value(again this is also done for each subject_id)? Just a caveat, this choice may vary depending on what is being worked out here, for example, any target value being predicted.

Comment: your assumption is right, but the reading not recorded for user any time , in this time i want calculate it based on matching between other rows,

Comment: i search for technique that make it , and found hot deck imputation could make what i want , but i didn't found how to implement it

Comment: Hope it helps a bit, https://github.com/tarikbir/missing_data_imputation#hot-deck-imputation 
https://github.com/tarikbir/missing_data_imputation/blob/master/imputation.py

Comment: thanks for your concern and time, i already found this, but the problem it designed for special format of data. can i adjust it to  run on csv file

Comment: I’m looking for the same answer. I’ve seen the code online but I’m looking for a general function written in Python that will take a column of my data frame and fill the missing values using the hot deck imputation technique.

Comment: after long search, i couldn't find,  there is only  exist in r packages , if you find in python please let me now. Note : hot deck is suitable when missing not more than 10%, if more than that you can use EM or MICE

Answer (score 0):

The hot-deck method is defined in the [literature](https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-missing-data-like-a-pro-part-2-imputation-methods-eabbf10b9ce4) as that method replaces missing values with randomly selected values from the current dataset on hand. So, I tried hot-deck methods to handle missing data such as the following code:

```
def hotdeck_imputation(data):
    
    for c in (data.columns):
        
        data.loc[:,c] = [random.choice(data[c].dropna()) if np.isnan(i) else i for i in data[c]]
    
    return data
```

I hope it helps with your problem.